# Почему не работает событие storage?

Tags: javascript, база-данных, localstorage

Имеется страница на которой при клике на определенную кнопку в localStorage перезаписываются данные.

Есть вторая страница к которой подключен `отдельный` файл .js в котором прописан следующий код:

```
window.addEventListener('storage', function() {
    alert(1)
})
```

Но событие ни в какую не срабатывает. Даже если я вручную удаляю или добавляю данные.

P.S. Я проверил на другие события, типа click, и они работают на этой странице, т.е. с подключением файла проблем нет.

В чем может быть проблема, я предполагаю, что это может быть из-за того, что .js файл в котором обновляется стор подключен к обеим страницам (файл с обработчиком подключен ко второй странице отдельно)

Answer (score 1):

> В чем может быть проблема

Октройте в браузере две закладки - с разными страницами или с одной и той же. В первой закладке выполните действия, приводящие к записи в `storage`. Во второй закладке произойдет событие `storage`.

Это событие - для изменений, сделанных *на другой* странице.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/StorageEvent

> A StorageEvent is sent to a window when a storage area it has access
>   to is changed within the context of *another* document.

Comment: так он же уточнил, что событие прослушивается на другой странице (не на той, где проходило изменение хранилища)

Comment: @Август "Я думаю, это неправильная печать." - "Осенний марафон"